# How to limit the UDP port range that WebRTC use?

Tags: javascript, udp, webrtc, kurento

I'm building a WebRTC application that used in corporation network that has limitation about how many port they can open.
Is there a way to programmatically set the limit range of UDP port that WebRTC using to generate ICE candidate and relay media?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the port range that Kurento uses in `/etc/kurento/modules/kurento/BaseRtpEndpoint.conf.ini` and then restarting the server. I don't know whether you can change these at runtime. (Sorry it's been a while).

But keep in mind you don't know how many endpoints WebRTC needs to set up so it needs to be a range.  The number can change based on the number of discovered addresses and networks on your side.  So if the other node is visible on many different addresses then many ports will need to be bound during the ICE negotiation. (and I don't remember how port re-use works with UDP so maybe you need to keep them dedicated).